# I need one word for adding and subtracting question

Tags: single-word-requests

A kid asked me a question to say one word for adding and subtracting question. The question goes

> While adding and subtracting we put ____ in a correct place.

We have to use one word in the blank space.

I am confused if the answer is "operation", "sign", "operator" or something else.

Comment: *Sums* can be used for the problem itself - it is sufficiently generic to include differences, though I think it is a [plurale tantum](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plurale_tantum). For the plus or minus sign itself, *operator* is fine. In your sample sentence, use it with a determiner - e.g. *the operator*.

Comment: @Lawrence  I think it's worth making  "the operator" an answer.

Comment: Thanks @k1eran. I've expanded the comment slightly to form an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Sums* can be used for the problem itself. It is sufficiently generic to include differences, though to my ear it is a [*plurale tantum*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plurale_tantum) (the term *sum* in the singular refers specifically to addition, as opposed to *difference*).

> **Sum** *noun*
> 3 An arithmetical problem, especially at an elementary level:
> *‘we did sums at school, Mummy’*
> [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sum)
>
> 2 [often plural] British a simple calculation. To do a sum is to calculate something.
> [- Macmillan Dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/sum_1)

You can refer to the plus sign or minus sign as an *operator*. In your sample sentence, use it with a determiner - e.g. the operator.

> **Operator** *noun*
> 4 *Mathematics* A symbol or function denoting an operation (e.g. ×, +).
> [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/operator)

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plus_and_minus_signs) (emphasis, mine):

> The plus sign (+) is a binary *operator* that indicates addition, as in 2 + 3 = 5.
> The subtraction operator: A binary *operator* to indicate the operation of subtraction, as in 5 − 3 = 2.

Your example sentence would then be completed in the following way:

- [When] adding and subtracting we put *the operator* in [the] correct place.